# Add custom action to Grails RestfulController

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I'm using Grails RestfulController to satisfy the following endpoint:

```
    GET /dayoffs    index
    GET /dayoffs/${id}  show
    GET /dayoffs/create create
    GET /dayoffs/${id}/edit edit
    POST    /dayoffs    save
    PUT /dayoffs/${id}  update
    DELETE  /dayoffs/${id}  delete

    PUT /dayoffs/${id}/approve
```

Dayoffs are requests made by an employee for time off. An admin is able to do a PUT request to the 'approve' action.

How can I make the grails RestfulController support my custom 'approve' request?

FYI: I know this is not 'exactly' restful but it is the requirements of my project. If it's not possible to do it with the RestfulController, I'd be open to suggestions on how to patch the action on some other way while keeping the standard rest methods in my Dayoffs RestfulController.

Comment: `PUT /dayoffs/${id}  update` You can [redirect](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html)/[forward](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html) from the default `update` action to your custom `approve` action.

Comment: Wouldn't the /approve part of the URL just get rejected though? As there is no matchings for it in the UrlMappings.groovy

Comment: May be I am not understanding it appropriately. Isn't `approve` doing the work of `update`?

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it "by hand".  Even then, things don't work quite the way I would like.

In UrlMappings, you probably have

```
static mappings = [
  "/dayoffs(resources: "dayoff") // Calls DayoffController
]
```

You can change that to

```
static mappings = [
  "/dayoffs(resources: "dayoff") {
    "/approve" (controller: "dayoff", action: "approve", method: "PUT")
  }
]
```

This will make sure that PUT requests to `/dayoffs/13/approve` will call your DayoffController's `approve` method with params.id set to 13.

Unfortunately, you will not be able to specify the requested format as part of the url with this (at least, I haven't been able to, even when using a mapping of `"/approve(.$format)"` instead).

If you find a better answer, please let me know!